# highcharts: plot unsorted data and also plot x-axis and y-axis against each other

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I would like to plot x-axis values against y-axis values (both being unsorted) against each other using high charts but when I am plotting the data it is starting from the least of x-axis values and plotting it, whatever the order of data is.
Is there any workaround to make it look like normal plot without any pre-ordering of data.
Here is my link to [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4y86mwyk/4/):

```js
//RESIZE THE CHART-SECTION TO SEE ISSUE (ARROW)

$(function() {

  (function(H) {

    var arrowCheck = false,
      pathTag;

    H.wrap(H.Series.prototype, 'drawGraph', function(proceed) {

      // Now apply the original function with the original arguments, 
      // which are sliced off this function's arguments
      proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));

      if (this.chart.options.plotOptions.showArrow) {
        // used a bit of regex to clean up the series name enough to be used as an id
        var arrowName = "arrow" + this.name.replace(/\W/g, "_").toLowerCase();

        var arrowLength = 15,
          arrowWidth = 9,
          series = this,
          data = series.data,
          len = data.length,
          segments = data,
          lastSeg = segments[segments.length - 1],
          path = [],
          lastPoint = null,
          nextLastPoint = null;

        if (lastSeg.y == 0) {
          lastPoint = segments[segments.length - 2];
          nextLastPoint = segments[segments.length - 1];
        } else {
          lastPoint = segments[segments.length - 1];
          nextLastPoint = segments[segments.length - 2];
        }

        var angle = Math.atan((lastPoint.plotX - nextLastPoint.plotX) /
          (lastPoint.plotY - nextLastPoint.plotY));

        if (angle < 0) angle = Math.PI + angle;

        path.push('M', lastPoint.plotX, lastPoint.plotY);

        if (lastPoint.plotX > nextLastPoint.plotX) {

          if (arrowCheck === true) {
            //replaced 'arrow' with arrowName
            pathTag = document.getElementById(arrowName);
            if (pathTag != null) {
              pathTag.remove(pathTag);
            }
          }

          path.push(
            'L',
            lastPoint.plotX + arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
            lastPoint.plotY - arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle)
          );
          path.push(
            lastPoint.plotX + arrowLength * Math.sin(angle),
            lastPoint.plotY + arrowLength * Math.cos(angle)
          );
          path.push(
            lastPoint.plotX - arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
            lastPoint.plotY + arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle),
            'Z'
          );
        } else {


          if (arrowCheck === true) {
            //replaced 'arrow' with arrowName
            pathTag = document.getElementById(arrowName);
            if (pathTag != null) {
              pathTag.remove(pathTag);
            }
          }

          path.push(
            'L',
            lastPoint.plotX - arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
            lastPoint.plotY + arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle)
          );
          path.push(
            lastPoint.plotX - arrowLength * Math.sin(angle),
            lastPoint.plotY - arrowLength * Math.cos(angle)
          );
          path.push(
            lastPoint.plotX + arrowWidth * Math.cos(angle),
            lastPoint.plotY - arrowWidth * Math.sin(angle),
            'Z'
          );
        }

        series.chart.renderer.path(path)
          .attr({
            fill: series.color,
            id: arrowName //changed from 'arrow' to arrowName to enable more than one series with an arrow
          })
          .add(series.group);

        arrowCheck = true;

      }
    });
  }(Highcharts));


  Highcharts.chart('graph-container-2', {
    chart: {
      type: 'spline',
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Chart example 2 (with NO arrow)'
    },
    xAxis: {
      reversed: false,
      maxPadding: 0.05,
      showLastLabel: true
    },
    yAxis: {
      lineWidth: 2
    },
    legend: {
      enabled: false
    },
    plotOptions: {
      spline: {
        marker: {
          enable: false
        }
      }
    },
    series: [{
      data: [
        [0, 15],
        [10, -50],
        [20, -56.5],
        [30, -46.5],
        [40, -22.1],
        [50, -2.5],
        [60, -27.7],
        [70, -55.7],
        [80, -76.5]
      ]
    }]
  });

  var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
      renderTo: 'graph-container-1',
      defaultSeriesType: 'scatter'
    },
    title: {
      text: 'Chart example 1 (WITH arrow)'
    },
    xAxis: {
      min: 0,
      max: 5
    },
    plotOptions: {

      series: {
        animation: {
          duration: 2000
        },
        lineWidth: 2,
        marker: {
          enabled: false
        }
      },

      states: {
        hover: {
          enabled: true,
          lineWidth: 2
        },

      },
      showArrow: true

    },

    series: [{
      name: 'main',
      id: 'main',
      data: [
        [4, 0],
        [3, 4],
        [4, 3]
      ]
    }]
  });

});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<body>
  <div>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#1" data-toggle="tab">Tab 1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#2" data-toggle="tab">Tab 2</a>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content">
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="1">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div id="graph-container-1" style="min-width: 500px; max-width: 800px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="tab-pane" id="2">
        <div class="col-md-6">
          <div id="graph-container-2" style="min-width: 500px; max-width: 800px; height: 300px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Check if this is what you are looking for https://www.highcharts.com/demo/combo-multi-axes

Comment: Why don't you simply apply simple `sort` function to your data? **Example:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/L2x6j84m/

Comment: Hi @KamilKulig, I would like to plot the unsorted data.

Comment: @AnandG No,It wasn't the one I was looking for.

Comment: So how exactly do you expect your series to look?